# Отключить OnItemSelectedListener на один вызов

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Не знаю как отключить все слушатели для `spinner` с помощью логической переменной. Сейчас мой код выглядит так:

```
onCreate(Bundle b) {
    //...
    disableListeners = true;
    spinner1.setSelection(2);
    spinner2.setSelection(2);
    spinner3.setSelection(2);
    disableListeners = false;
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> p, View v, int pos, long id) {
    if (!disableListeners) handleItemSelected(p, v, id);
}
```

Но это не работает, потому что слушатели включаются раньше вызова `onItemSelected()`. Переносить их включение в `onItemSeleted` нет возможности.

Comment: Передать нул - нет ? )

Comment: А Вы подскажите для чего Вам это нужно - возможно можно решить проблему совершенно иначе.